# TypeScript: Is it possible to make a function that uses a generic type to determine which key of the object it can take as its params

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sorry if the title sounds confusing. Essentially what I am trying to do is that I want to make a function that takes an object and a key of that object, where the key might be nested inside of the object and has to be a specific type specified in the generics. So like

```
type Key = {
  key1: Key1;
};
type Key1 = {
  key2: Key2;
};
type Key2 = {
  status: Status;
};

type Status = "Active" | "Inactive";
interface MyObject {
  key: Key;
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
  key: {
    key1: {
      key2: {
        status: "Active"
      }
    }
  }
};


//  this is the function I am trying to build
foo<MyObject, Status>(myObject, 'status')
```

Here I have a function `foo`, which takes two arguments. And the second argument is a `key` on the object(it could be nested so it is not necessarily on the initial level of the object) and it is of the type `Status`, in this case the key we can pass is `status`.

So if you change `Status` to `Key2` then you can only pass `key2` as the second argument because `key2` is of the type `Key2`.

I am not sure if this is even possible with TypeScript. I guess I will need to do some sort of recursive generics but I am not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: So you're looking for [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints), but recursive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this recursive type definition can you help you. It does deviate from your desired signature of `foo`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7AchAzigJgaQhCwBUB7AVVQEszUAeEgPigF4oBvAKCigG18UaqigBrImQBmUEgF0AXDIGyoEAB4pUuLFDIAjAFYQAxsCg9eUAPyxEyNJhwQCRUpRp1GylgB8o+C15FAIBfPnEQKRlZLi5QSH9XNlskTUc8QmJyKloGAFkQAHlDE2AmAG5Y+OhM5O5eCIBGYKJGypDK6sSQRrqLCIAmFpAB9s7wGqIBvt4cJABXLEUAZWAFrDGqiahV9eSAIgBBU2oANwh9qD99gElUBBPz-crhFAAnSQfoAuKjU05+kRhu1YsY6DgoABbIolUyKH6wszsepiIEAyyonqKFEYwbYwIYqBzYCLRRHR4XAm8EIEmnUrgdWKSeaoE50KCSMhkAAUZHhML+wAANJjFPBUg5sBlXNkPPkBaUmABKdFQMGoLBkOAQAB0cDIAHNeSKIkrKrwAPQWqA621QfUG6jGcw0ricnnQ36lEX7YmLfZKrhAA)
Given:

```
type Key = {
  key1: Key1;
};
type Key1 = {
  key2: Key2;
};
type Key2 = {
  status: Status;
};

type Status = "Active" | "Inactive";
interface MyObject {
  key: Key;
}
```

Go through the object's keys and if the value extends `object`, union that recursive type with the key that started the recursion. Otherwise, just take the key.

```
type FlattenNestedKeysToUnion<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object 
    ? FlattenNestedKeysToUnion<T[K]> | K
    : K
}[keyof T]

// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
function foo<T extends MyObject>(o: T, key: FlattenNestedKeysToUnion<T>) {
  // ... logic 
}
```

However, `tsc` does complain that this type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite for type `T` in `FlattenNestedKeysToUnion<T>`. I don't think there is a prescribed or idiomatic, way to solve that error besides something like the below hack which avoids generics and define `foo` like so:

```
function foo(o: MyObject, key: FlattenNestedKeysToUnion<MyObject>) {
  // ... logic 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reclusively check if key's value extends the required type:

```
type KeysOfType<T, TValue> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TValue ? K : T[K] extends object ? KeysOfType<T[K], TValue> : never
}[keyof T];

declare function foo<TObject, TValue>(obj: TObject, key: KeysOfType<TObject, TValue>): void;

foo<MyObject, Status>(myObject, 'status')
foo<MyObject, Status>(myObject, 'bar') // Argument of type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"status"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQN4Cgqaga3gRgC5Z8BuNAXzNEmJDyVQy1xACYi42zK1rpPWDdFigBnYAENgAV1FEAypJmiyIgEYSATkQB20gLZqImimV7hoiqbIYAiAIIBjYAEsAbhFtQAPlFsBJHQlnd08yFx1gYwAzYOgAWRAAeTUAKwhnRhEWDnhuNDRHAHsdcSh9ZLSM4CJElPTM5GFmeCJmkUwWQiyO3pZ2Ht6hsSVZIgcQj1sAGiZh3o1tKDxWAGY5%20fINkS2d0wK%20WlEk6IAVCwAeU%20moU4A1CQAbaQgAPiENgG0YKAiceCK0VuAF0iKdvsCoBAAB5RHQAE1Etwez2gAH5YFAwRCobCIAikUUqpkMZxjmdLuCYMCbvcni93roIB4TORPixASCzPCMo8tNBotIdCESlBokUild6tVaSiGQAKImpMHS5w3HJHE7nSBS4nAWX0t4ASiIbiKLnhZnFkrqepuVmUr3lFVV%20qgAHJxNZRO6jWhrRdbQ03Q7ZE6XXaPYtfVAAPSxqD2TQAcwM%20OAUE5h3dtkWtndvyROiKGYkolELmTQTUj2gwCKUDAWgk%20ggUU0maB2dsXuU%20YAdEA)